# Same String, different hash codes

Tags: java, scala, hashcode

I am coding a simple lookup that somehow always fails. Investigating further, I have found something I can't explain: It seems that while my strings are identical, they don't get the same hash code.

```
fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jSeduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder Hex: 66722E756E6963652E6933732E6D6F64616C69732E6A536564756974652E746563686E6963616C2E72657374617572616E742E436F7572736546696E646572 Hash code: 1515256474
fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jseduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder Hex: 66722E756E6963652E6933732E6D6F64616C69732E6A736564756974652E746563686E6963616C2E72657374617572616E742E436F7572736546696E646572 Hash Code: 2099127532
```

Repeating the experiment with Java 6, I get a similar issue. Note that either way, things are not constant:

```
fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jSeduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder Hex: 66722E756E6963652E6933732E6D6F64616C69732E6A536564756974652E746563686E6963616C2E72657374617572616E742E436F7572736546696E646572 Hash code: 1515256474
fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jseduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder Hex: 66722E756E6963652E6933732E6D6F64616C69732E6A736564756974652E746563686E6963616C2E72657374617572616E742E436F7572736546696E646572 Hash Code:  - 1772912571
```

My code relies on this match, and I don't want to run a .equals() as it would likely be too slow.

From what I understand, the hash code should be identical for identical strings. Is this a bug in the JVM? Is there some magical Scala interference involved?

Environment:

- Scala 2.10
- 64 bit Oracle Java 1.7.0_17 and Oracle Java 1.6.0_43
- IntelliJ IDEA (latest community version)

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the different hashcodes?

Comment: What hash library are you using? Is it thread safe?

Comment: Can you show us the actual strings so we can check the hashcodes for them?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think `fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jSeduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder` => 1515256474 and `fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jseduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder` => -296330566 (not sure why the second one does not match the op's result though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jSeduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder`

`!=`

`fr.unice.i3s.modalis.jseduite.technical.restaurant.CourseFinder`

(`jSeduite != jseduite`)